# How to initialize UILabel when added to the Prototype Cell in Swift

Tags: swift

In Objective C, I could do use this:

```
UILabel *dareTitleLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:3];
```

I tried using this in Swift:

```
var dareLabel:UILabel=UILabel(dare:UILabel!. viewWithTag(1))
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Postfix '.' is reserved

How can I solve this?

Comment: The edited Swift code has a period between the initializer parameters instead of a comma.

Answer (score 3):

Have you even started reading the Apple's guide on Swift? More to the point, there are a few things specifically you would have known if you did:

1. Method calls: `[object method:param]` is `object.method(param)` in Swift.
2. Type casting: `(UILabel *) x` is `x as UILabel` in Swift.

So,

```
var dareLabel: UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(3) as UILabel
```

Or, since the variable type can be inferred by Swift,

```
var dareLabel = cell.viewWithTag(3) as UILabel
```

And if you are not going to reassign to this variable, you probably should use a constant instead,

```
let dareLabel = cell.viewWithTag(3) as UILabel
```